# Write a regex that should match a format "02142-1209"

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Need to write Proper Regex that will maximum 9 digits and regex will match "02142-1209", but if anyone is mentioning 5 digits also then we can allow user to submit.
Maximum 9digits, and it should have "-" included within it.

Note- User can able to submit if he added first 5 digits.

```
if ( !props.postalCode )
  {
    err.postalCode = "Zip Code is Required.";
  } else if ( props.countryCode === "US" && !/^[\d]+\-*[\d]\{9}$/.test( props.postalCode ) )
  {
    err.postalCode = "US Zip Codes Must Be 5 Digits";
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should match 5 digits, and optionally 4 more digits. The hyphen in between is optional.

```
/^[0-9]{5}-?([0-9]{4})?$/
```

I've used this library which also handles international postal codes:
https://github.com/Cimpress-MCP/postal-codes-js/